# List view button clicked switch into the form view? in Odoo V13

Tags: python, odoo

I'm migrating the code from V7 to V13, i see the symbol present in V7 is not shown in V13 while migrating. Is this by default or we need to add it from the custom widget.
For eg.,

[image: Image From V7]

As per the image in the right corner i see there is a list view and form view symbol.

How can we see the same in V13? I have seen few documents but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Odoo views show either multi record or single record.

**Multi record**

- list view (aka tree view)
- kanban view
- gantt view
- graph view
- pivot view

**Single record**

- form view

Prior to Odoo Version 12.0, all views are shown on the right of the control panel whereas in Version 12.0+ only the multi record views are displayed.

When you click on an item in the list view, the view automatically changes to that records' form view. When you then click on the list view icon, or on the breadcrumbs, the list view is shown again.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So, there is no option in V13 to switch from form to tree and vice versa ? we just need to continue by clicking on list view to get form view and using breadcrumbs go back to list view ?